# Django Models: init.py Import Error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, module

So I have my ordinary DJango project, with a selection of add ons:

- Django Oauth Toolkit
- Django Rest Framework
- CORS

So it was working up until I started creating custom "retrieve" request in a Rest Framework View Set. To help, the traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application, run
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import ISO_8859_1, UTF_8
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SERCETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/DIRNAME/SECRETDIR/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals  # NOQA
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

So thats that, I have hidden some personal information, but if you need any more info, I can add it.

I am using a signal, at one point in the project, but I hadn't done anything to it to break it, and Django is V1.9 according to pip.

For your info, I only use one `models.py` for the whole project, to save confusion.

Below is the snippet of my only `models.py`:
 `

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import string
import uuid
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from random import randint

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import random
from django.utils.html import format_html
from helpers import fields # Doesn't import this file


class CardHolder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rest_framework')
    card_number = fields.CardNumberField(unique=True, max_length=16)  # My special field
    authentication_code = models.IntegerField()
    transaction_auth_code = models.BigIntegerField()
    universal_user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    client_sign_up_key = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="hi")

    def generate_attr(self):
        self.authentication_code = randint(0, 2147483647)  # 2147483647 is IntegerFields top limit
        self.transaction_auth_code = randint(0, 9223372036854775807)
        self.card_number = generate_card_number(max_length=16, min_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def client(self):
        try:
            if len(self.user.groups.all()) > 0:
                user_group = self.user.groups.all().last()
                print "Here: ", self.user, ' ', user_group
                client = Client.objects.get(name=user_group.name)
                print client
                universal_client_id = client.universal_client_id
                client_url = "/admin/{}/client/{}/change".format(self._meta.app_label, universal_client_id)
                return format_html("<span><a href='{}'>{}</a></span>".format(client_url, client.name))
            else:
                return "No Clients :("
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def generate_client_sign_up_key(self):
        size = 20
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        code = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
        self.client_sign_up_key = code
        self.save()
        return code


client_image_choices = (
    ('SQ', 'Square'),
    ('RC', 'Rectangle'),
    ('RO', 'Round')
)


class Client(models.Model):
    temp = False

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="NAME")
    email = models.EmailField(default="sam@themasons.org")

    colour_style = models.CharField(default="ff0000", max_length=8, help_text="Please remove any # from the front")
    icon = models.FileField(default="logo.png", help_text="If you can, please upload a square/round icon, not a big "
                                                          "rectangular shape.")
    image_shape = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=client_image_choices)

    website = models.URLField(max_length=500, default="https://example.com/")
    request_url_segment = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="api/request")
    login_url_segment = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="api/login")
    universal_client_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="HI")
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deletion_key = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def create_random_key(self, term_length, do_return_object):
        random_key = randint(0, 9999999999999999)
        date_time_created = datetime.now
        random_key_object = ClientRandomKey(client=self, random_key=random_key, date_time_created=date_time_created,
                                            valid_term_length=term_length)
        random_key_object.save()

        if do_return_object:
            return random_key_object

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        group = Group.objects.get(name=self.name)
        group.delete()
        super(Client, self).delete()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    def transactions_for_client(self):
        transactions_for_client = TransactionLogItem.objects.filter(client=self)
        return transactions_for_client

    def generate_deletion_key(self):
        size = 20
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        code = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
        self.deletion_key = code
        self.save()
        return code


class TransactionLogItem(models.Model):
    expiry_length = 100  # In days

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    card_holder = models.ForeignKey(CardHolder)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="A transaction")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def make_invisible(self):
        print "here"
        self.visible = False
        self.save()

    def get_client(self):
        return Client.objects.get(universal_client_id=self.client.universal_client_id)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Transaction for {}".format(self.card_holder)


class ClientRandomKey(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    random_key = models.BigIntegerField()
    date_time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    valid_term_length = models.IntegerField()  # Number of days that the Key is valid for.

    def get_finishing_date(self):
        start_date_time = self.date_time_created
        valid_term_length = self.valid_term_length

        finish_date = start_date_time + timedelta(days=valid_term_length)
        return finish_date

    def is_valid(self):
        if self.get_finishing_date() == datetime.now() or self.get_finishing_date() < datetime.now():
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def __str__(self):
        return "Random Key for: {}".format(self.client)


    def generate_card_number(**kwargs):
        """
        Generates card number, used definitely in CardHolder.generate_attr()

        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            max_length = kwargs["max_length"]
            min_length = kwargs["min_length"]

            value = []
            if max_length >= min_length:
                if max_length % 4 == 0:
                    segment_length = max_length / 4

                    for s in range(segment_length):
                        segment = random.randint(1000, 9999)
                        value.append(segment)

                    temp_value_str = map(str, value)
                    temp_value_parsed = "".join(temp_value_str)

                    return temp_value_parsed
                else:
                    return None
            else:
                raise ValueError("min_length is greater than max_length")
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

`

Comment: Are you starting ti with `manage.py runserver`? Also `settings.py` (removing personal info) and django version (we can guess the python version from your error) are a must for anyone to be able to help.  `from django.db.models import signals` works perfectly form me with the latest dajngo (1.10).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using './manage.py runserver' on a mac

Comment: Check your models for circular imports. Something like importing ModelTwo in first app, and importing ModelOne in the second app.

Comment: @andrey-shipilov Tried that, taken out anything that even could have a loop, but still doesn't work! :(

Comment: The error you're getting is most likely the circular import. Can you share some code of your models?

Comment: @andrey-shipilov Added models up above